# Disable auto log off windows server 2012

Tags: windows, remote-desktop, user-accounts, group-policy

How to disable auto log off feature for a **specific user** in windows server 2012 using rdp

Thanks for your time.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Disable Windows Server 2012 automatic log off](http://superuser.com/questions/558920/disable-windows-server-2012-automatic-log-off)

Comment: @RomeoNinov i had it referred already, please note that there is no viable option for implementing those settings on a specific user in it. :)

Comment: @Corleone - Expand your question then, beause thats how you would do it, we need more information then "it doesn't work"

Comment: @Ramhound the link (resolution) shared enables the settings not for a single user. please let me know how do i proceed

Comment: With a user with the correct permissions they can change the group policy just for them.

Comment: @Ramhound my user is with Admin privileges kindly suggest further steps

Comment: I have asked you to provide more information, you have failed to do that, so I can't kindly suggest additional steps beyond what is in the duplicate question which can be used to solve your problem.

Comment: @Ramhound can you elaborate on the further information which is required

Answer (score 0):

To specify timeout and reconnection settings for a remote session:

On the RD Session Host server, open Remote Desktop Session Host Configuration. To open Remote Desktop Session Host Configuration, click Start, point to Administrative Tools, point to Remote Desktop Services, and then click Remote Desktop Session Host Configuration.

Under Connections, right-click the name of the connection, and then click Properties.

In the Properties dialog box for the connection, on the Sessions tab, select the following options as necessary:

Select the Override user settings check box, and then set timeout settings for End a disconnected session, Active session limit, and Idle session limit.

Select the Override user settings check box, and then select one of the following reconnection settings: Disconnect from session or End session.

Click OK.

Changes to timeout and reconnection settings are not applied to sessions that are connected when the change is made. The changes will take effect the next time the user establishes a new connection to the RD Session Host server.
You can also configure timeout and reconnection settings by applying the following Group Policy settings:

Set time limit for disconnected sessions
Set time limit for active but idle Remote Desktop Services sessions
Set time limit for active Remote Desktop Services sessions
Terminate session when time limits are reached
These Group Policy settings are located in the following locations:

Computer Configuration\Policies\Administrative Templates\Windows Components\Remote Desktop Services\Remote Desktop Session Host\Session Time Limits

User Configuration\Policies\Administrative Templates\Windows Components\Remote Desktop Services\Remote Desktop Session Host\Session Time Limits
These Group Policy settings can be configured by using either the Local Group Policy Editor or the Group Policy Management Console (GPMC).